# Installing Ubuntu 13.10 on new Macbook Pro. Installs then fails after restart

Tags: system-installation, startup, macbook, restart

So I installed Ubuntu from a Live USB. No problems there. I get to the end of the the installation and am told to restart. I restart it then get a white screen with a blinking file icon with a question mark in it. Ubuntu is installed as if I try to install again it says Ubuntu is running when you are asked whether you want to erase the previous operating system.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe Macs are able to use Ubuntu natively. I think you need a third-party bootloader such as rEFInd. Although if you still have Mac OS X installed I seriously recommend you use this tool: [Mac linux USB loader](http://sevenbits.github.io/Mac-Linux-USB-Loader/)

Comment: I used a boot loader..i went through the whole installation, it just seems like it won't start up? Thanks for the answer though :)